# Recording with both a Multi-Effects Pedal and a Modelling Amplifier at the same time

Tags: recording, amplifiers, guitar-effects, effects-pedal

I want to achieve a setup where I have a guitar plugged in to a multi-effects pedal (the Zoom G1XON to be precise) going to a modelling amp (the Marshall Code 25); I want to then use the modelling amp as a USB interface to record my guitar directly into a DAW. If I do this, will I still be able to record the effects on the multi-effects pedal even though it in itself is not connected to the computer directly?

I ask this because I already have a Zoom G1XON (which unfortunately doesn't allow for direct USB recording), and am looking to purchase a modelling amplifier that lets me record directly into my computer. I know that the modelling amplifier also comes with some built in effects, but I would like to be able to use some pedal based effects (like the wah) from the Zoom G1XON while recording. I also find that the effects pedal has some effects that are not found on the modelling amplifier and would like to be able to incorporate some of those effects while recording.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you are plugging the guitar into the zoom, and then the zoom into the marshal, why wouldn't you hear the zoom effects?

Comment: I know I would hear it while playing through the amp, but I am not sure this would be true if I try to record the sounds I'm getting using the amp as a USB interface.

Comment: Still not sure why you think the marshal might strip the zoom effects. Even if the USB-to-daw audio was the "clean, untouched" input that the Marshal receives (bypassing all Marshall effects and modeling), that input is from the ZOOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the signal going to the amp has the effects already applied by the Zoom, yes of course you can do this. The Marshall will apply the amp model - it cannot strip the effects off as all it receives is the audio.